Unable to read an empty file in dask
I have some py code to compare a given pair of files. I am using dask for lazy computation. There could sometimes be an empty file in one of the files. When I try to read an empty file with headers, it always fails.

Input file is empty (input.csv)

Python code:
import dask.dataframe as dd
file='input.csv'
read_source_file_kwargs = {'sep': '|', 'header': None, 'names': ['column1', 'column2']}
df = dd.read_csv(file, **read_source_file_kwargs)


Error message:


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 dd.read_csv('input.csv', **read_source_file_kwargs).compute()

File ~/miniconda3/envs/rs/Lib/site-packages/dask/backends.py:142, in CreationDispatch.register_inplace.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    140     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    141 except Exception as e:
--> 142     raise type(e)(
    143         f"An error occurred while calling the {funcname(func)} "
    144         f"method registered to the {self.backend} backend.\n"
    145         f"Original Message: {e}"
    146     ) from e

ValueError: An error occurred while calling the read_csv method registered to the pandas backend.
Original Message: All `iterables` must have a non-zero length

Is this expected? How do I fix this?
I was hoping to get an empty dataframe whenever the file being read was empty.
When I use Pandas to read the same file as follows, it works:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, **read_source_file_kwargs)


You can check whether or not the file is empty by using the os.stat() function like this:
import os
import dask.dataframe as dd

file='input.csv'
read_source_file_kwargs = {'sep': '|', 'header': None, 'names': ['column1', 'column2']}

if os.stat(file).st_size != 0
        df = dd.read_csv(file, **read_source_file_kwargs)
else
        # do something else




thanks @ibemeltin ! This mitigates the problem. I created a function that does this:
def read_csv(file_path,**kwargs):
    import dask.dataframe as dd 
    import pandas as pd 
    if os.stat(file_path).st_size != 0:
        df = dd.read_csv(file_path, **kwargs)
        print(f"File {file_path} size not 0")
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, **kwargs)
        df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
        print(f"File {file_path} size 0")
            # do something else
    return df

